# Joomla: news in blog

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

This might be a really simple question and I apologise if it has been asked before but i haven't found an answer.

My Homepage list only news (blog)...(no menu left, no menu right in sidebar)
When an user clicks on article it show the article in the same homepage.
What i would like to have is
When an user click articles in the home page it will be redirecting to another menu (news) where it shows a menu with news list items on the left sidebar and the content of the article clicked in the content.

Is that Possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a custom module with left side bar and right content.In left sidebar put the query to populate news title from the selected category.On right display introtext or full text from #_content table based on article id.

Comment: Thank you for answer, thats works,but now I have problem at my Homepage
I have 2 categories: News and Featured
The only way thats works is to set Featured Articles. It gets them form both categories (featart1, featart2, featnewsart1, featnewsart2 )and when i click on my featnewsartx it redirect in the right menu as you explained but now my problem is that i cant see my normal news.
How can i see all my news (feat. and norm.) in the homepage? If i use blog in the home page clicking on a news it give me a conflict error with two elements targeting the same category)
Thank You for your help

Comment: Thank you...that was useful....do You have some links where can i find some specific examples to build a new component like that quickly?...Especially for target... Which module i have to copy?I just started using Joomla and i dont have a lot of reference.. .. I have already made a module for blog template tought

Comment: Check out these links   http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing     http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/7314.you can use these modules to list articles on left side bar.Check demo and use

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a hidden menu to show the news in inner page. Go to menu manager and create a new menu with title Hidden Menu and menu type hidden. Inside that menu add new menu item of type article category blog.select the category from where these front page articles come .Save it and check the front end of the site.

Comment: Great....everything works perfect Now....Now I fully understand what u mean...I had lost some passage....Thank you